# Update Gstreamer to latest version

Tags: gnome, gstreamer

I get this message in logs, how to update to latest version.

```
Gst version 1.17.0.1 is installed but Pitivi requires at least version 1.17.90
```

Comment: What OS/release are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 lts.@guiverc